# Run python script in Tkinter with path to image loaded in Tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I create a code to make an app with Tkinter. In this app I have a button and with this button I want to run an other Python script to do some image processing with an image that already is opened in Tkinter.

```
def run_command():
    os.system('python Fontane.py')
```

So in the script Fontane.py I want to create a path to the image that is loaded with the following code:

```
def select_image():
    global panelA, panelB

    path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

    if len(path) > 0:
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        scale_percent = 40
        width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

So the question is, how do I create a path that leads to the image that I loaded in Tkinter?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `os.system('python Fontane.py')` instead of `import Fontane`?

Comment: You told us what you want to do, but haven't asked a question. What sort of help do you need?

Comment: Sorry, the question is how do I create a path that leads to the image that I loaded in Tkinter? @Bryan Oakley

Comment: Did you try `.imwrite()` function to save the image to file?

Comment: When I try to imwrite to image, I get the following error : ValueError: Axes=(0, 1) out of range for array of ndim=0. Any idea to fix this?